# Is there any non-trivial sense in which the spacetime symmetries in the SM gauge QFT are made local?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, poincare-symmetry

I know there is a trivial sense in which they are made local by tensoring them with the internal local gauge symmetries through a direct product as per Coleman-Mandula theorem, but it bothers me a bit that the global or affine transformations of Poincaré are inherently $x^\mu$-independent while local interacting renormalized fields are inherently $x^\mu$-dependent.

Comment: You make Poincaré local, you essentially get gravitation.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Right, I figured going to curved spacetime was the only way so the answer to my question is "no". Just making sure.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Please let me know if I understand this correctly. By making Poincare local you get the type of gravity like the one you experience in an accelerating rocket, but not the type with a polar symmetry like in the case of a heavy object like a star. The spacetime curvature is different in these two case, is it not? Or am I wildly off?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform However, there is still something I fail to see, even in the "trivial" sense in which a local Poincaré symmetry is used in the Standard model QFT to reflect the fact that we are dealing with local interactions fields constructed from unirreps of the "local" Poincaré, symmetry(i.e. the semidirect product of Minkowski translations and proper, orthochronous Lorentz group) one still has that this symmetry has by definition independence of coordinate position while the actual local renormalized field doesn't,does this even come up or am I seeing things that aren't there?